Kernel of the Evaluation Homomorphism
Let $z, w \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ and let $\Phi_{z,w} : \mathbb{R}[X, Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the evaluation homomorphism defined by $f \mapsto f(z, w)$. Show that $\ker(\Phi_{z,w})$ is generated by one linear polynomial and one polynomial of degree 2.
To start, the kernel is defined as:
$$\ker(\Phi_{z,w}) = \{ f \in \mathbb{R}[X, Y] \mid f(z, w) = 0 \}$$
My idea is that I need to argue that $g(X,Y) = Y- aX - b,$ which would be our linear polynomial and our quadratic polynomial would be $h(X,Y) = (X-w)(Y-z).$
I just can't find any good reasoning for proving this generates the kernel of $\Phi.$
Hope that someone can help.

Obviously the first step is to consider some examples and calculate the kernel.

@MartinBrandenburg Something like $f(X,Y) = (X-z)(Y-w)$ evaluated at $(z,w)$ gives $f(X,Y) = 0.$ So thats in the kernel. So the kernel could be $\langle X-z, Y-w \rangle$ ? Since $f(X,Y) = X-z$ evaluated at $(z,w)$ is also $0$.

Your generators must have real coefficients.

@DrTokus No, I meant choosing specific complex numbers and then compute the kernel. What about taking  both to be $i$?

First, observe that $\mathbb{R}[X, Y] \cong \mathbb{R}[X][Y]$. Let $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ be the minimal polynomial for $z$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Next, convince yourself that $\mathbb{R}[X]/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb{C}$ by the map $h \mapsto h(z)$. It follows that there exists $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such with $\overline{g}(x)$ the image of $g(x)$ in the quotient $\mathbb{R}[X]/(f(x))$, $\overline{g}(z) = w$. Given that $f(x)$ is a degree 2 polynomial, we can take $g$ to be linear (if we initially chose a non-linear $g$, write $g$ as $q(x)f(x) + r(x)$ with $\deg r(x) < 2$ and redefine $g(x)$ to be $r(x)$.)
Thus, we have $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb{C}[Y]$ by the evaluation map $h \mapsto h(z)$. Clearly, $\mathbb{C}[Y]/(Y - w) \cong \mathbb{C}$ by the evaluation map $h \mapsto h(w)$ and the composition of these two evaluation maps is $\Phi_{z, w}$. Identifying elements of $\mathbb{C}$ with linear polynomials in $x$ under the isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}[X]/(f(x))$ we see that the composition of our two maps gives an isomorphism
$\big ( R[X, Y]/(f(x)) \big ) \big / \big ((f(x),y-(x+c))/(f(x))\big ) \cong \mathbb{C}$
By the third isomorphism theorem for rings, it follows that the kernel of $\Phi_{z, w} = (f(x), y-(x+c))$, proving the claim.
